# How to run mkfs on file image partitions without mounting?

Tags: linux, parted, mkfs

I am creating an empty file...

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=${SDCARD} bs=1 count=0 seek=$(expr 1024 \* ${SDCARD_SIZE})
```

...then turning it into an drive image...

```
parted -s ${SDCARD} mklabel msdos
```

...and creating partitions on it

```
parted -s ${SDCARD} unit KiB mkpart primary fat32 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} $(expr ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} \+ ${BOOT_SPACE_ALIGNED})
parted -s ${SDCARD} unit KiB mkpart primary $(expr  ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} \+ ${BOOT_SPACE_ALIGNED}) $(expr ${IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT} \+ ${BOOT_SPACE_ALIGNED} \+ $ROOTFS_SIZE)
```

How do I use `mkfs.ext` and `mkfs.vfat` *without* mounting this image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to format a partition in a disk-image file, rather than the entire image file.  In that case, you need to use `losetup` to tell linux to use the  image file as a loopback device.

NOTE: `losetup` requires root privileges, so must be run as root or with sudo.  The `/dev/loop*` devices it uses/creates also require root privs to access and use.

e.g (as root)

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 ./sdcard.img

# fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 1 MiB, 1048576 bytes, 2048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x54c246ab

Device       Boot Start   End Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1          1  1023    1023 511.5K  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/loop0p2       1024  2047    1024   512K 83 Linux

# file -s /dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p1: data

# mkfs.vfat /dev/loop0p1 
mkfs.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Loop device does not match a floppy size, using default hd params

# file -s /dev/loop0p1
/dev/loop0p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 4, root entries 512, sectors 1023 (volumes <=32 MB) , Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 1, sectors/track 32, heads 64, serial number 0xfa9e3726, unlabeled, FAT (12 bit)
```

and, finally, detach the image from the loopback device:

```
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

See `man losetup` for more details.

Comment: Note that mounting / partitioning loopback devices does not always cause kernel to re-read partition table, therefore one should either run `partprobe` afterwards or initially invoke `losetup` with `-P, --partscan` option. See this answer for details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425641/30230

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. The question is how to do this "without mounting", and losetup is the same thing as doing a loop mount of the file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073467/are-these-processes-basically-the-same-sudo-mount-o-loop-imagefile-mntpoint

Comment: @Étienne you are mistaken, and you have misunderstood the Q you linked to - it is asking if one command (`mount -o loop ...`) is basically the same as two (`losetup ...; mount ...`).  `losetup` is not the same as mounting a filesystem. It tells the kernel to assign one of the loopback devices to a file so it can be treated as if it were a block device, including partitioning it and formatting one or more of the partitions with `mkfs`.  The partitioning can be done without `losetup`, but the formatting can not because mkfs has no option to use an offset.

Comment: @cas what I meant is that a typical use-case for wanting to avoid a mount-loop is to perform parallel builds which don't interfere with each others when using loop devices, and also to avoid running as root. The reply below with mformat allows both things. Using losetup allows neither, so while it is working I wonder what the advantage of losetup vs loop mount is.

Comment: @Étienne you're missing the obvious. again.  The advantage of using `losetup` rather than `mount` is that it **doesn't** mount anything, which is **exactly** what the OP asked for.   `mount -o loop` is effectively just a short-cut for `losetup ...; mount ...`.

Comment: BTW, the OP said nothing about not wanting to run any commands as root, that's entirely your imagination - which isn't really much use as justification for declaring "this should not be the accepted answer".   Your other imaginary criterion, performing multiple parallel builds, is also not relevant...and isn't even a problem - the kernel's loop driver defaults to 8 devices, but its `max_loop` option can override that (up to, IIRC, a maximum of 256 loop devices).

Answer (score 12):

To create an image with multiple partitions, a solution that doesn't require any fancy tools or root access is to first create the filesystems, then concatenate them.

```
truncate -s $IMAGE_ROOTFS_ALIGNMENT disk
truncate -s $BOOT_SPACE_ALIGNED part1
mkfs.fat part1
cat part1 >>disk
truncate -s $ROOTFS_SIZE part2
mkfs.ext4 part2
cat part2 >>disk
```

Then run `parted` or `fdisk` to create the partitions.

This approach has the downside that the resulting image won't be sparse.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the answer provided by @gilles, here's one way to create a disk image containing a formatted filesystem by first creating a filesystem (of type ESP in this example) within a file and then assembling that to a valid disk image; no root, mounts or loop devices required:

```
diskimg=diskimg    # filename of resulting disk image
size=$((260*(1<<20))) # desired size in bytes, 260MB in this case
alignment=1048576  # align to next MB (https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment)
size=$(( (size + alignment - 1)/alignment * alignment ))  # ceil(size, 1MB)

# mkfs.fat requires size as an (undefined) block-count; seem to be units of 1k
mkfs.fat -C -F32 -n "volname" "${diskimg}".fat $((size >> 10))

# insert the filesystem to a new file at offset 1MB
dd if="${diskimg}".fat of="${diskimg}" conv=sparse obs=512 seek=$((alignment/512))
# extend the file by 1MB
truncate -s "+${alignment}" "${diskimg}"

# apply partitioning
parted --align optimal "${diskimg}" mklabel gpt mkpart ESP "${offset}B" '100%' set 1 boot on
```

The above approach has the side-benefit of being sparse when used on a filesystem that supports sparse files; the resulting "262MB" file occupies less than 200kB on disk:

```
du -h --apparent diskimg; du -h diskimg
262M    diskimg
196K    diskimg
```

For FAT filesystems the [Mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html) utilities support operating on an offset into a file (ext2/4/etc probably do as well?). This makes it easier, you just create the partitioned image and work on that directly:

```
diskimg=diskimg
size=$((260*(1<<20))) # desired size in bytes, 260MB in this case
# align to next MB (https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment)
alignment=1048576

size=$(( (size + alignment - 1)/alignment * alignment ))

# image size is gpt + filesystem size + gpt backup
truncate -s $((size + 2*alignment)) "${diskimg}"

parted --machine --script --align optimal "${diskimg}" mklabel gpt mkpart ESP "${alignment}B" '100%' set 1 boot on

mformat -i "${diskimg}"@@"${alignment}" -t $((size>>20)) -h 64 -s 32 -v "volname"
```

Here's a diagram of the resulting image file:

[image: partitioned image file]

Comment: This is great, its just missing the part of how to add another (root) partition to the image, probably ext4. How would I extend the code?

Answer (score 0):

Since @user310346's answer proved particularly tricky and fragile to adapt for producing FAT16 filesystems for use in Box86, I spent a while wrestling with it and came up with three useful things to say:

**First**, most of that boilerplate in user310346's answer is for allowing you to specify an arbitrary *partition* size in bytes and then calculate the drive size from it, with appropriate rounding. If you're willing to specify an *image/drive* size (which I *need* to do because
I'm trying to match a CHS preset from Box86), then parted can automate deriving the rest from it.

**Second**, the [Parted manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html) from 2002 lists `mkfs` and `mkpartfs` commands that should theoretically be able to do this sort of thing, so it'd be worth looking through the changelogs to see what became of them. Maybe they just morphed into something more obscure but still not requiring root permissions.

**Third**, thanks to the [Bochs manual](https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/diskimagehowto.html), I discovered that, if you're going to use mtools, it's easier to get a working filesystem if you have it do *all* the work.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")" || exit

SRC_DIR="combined_disk"
IMG_NAME="combined_disk.img"

# Size for the hard drive image
# (Here's one that's in 86Box's CHS presets)
CYLINDERS=1036
HEADS=16
SECTORS=63

# Work around partition=1 not being possible on the command-line AFAIK
mtools_tmp="$(mktemp -d --tmpdir make_disk.XXXXXXXXXX)"
mtools_conf="${mtools_tmp}/mtoolsrc"
echo "drive c: file=\"${IMG_NAME}\" partition=1" >"$mtools_conf"
export MTOOLSRC="${mtools_conf}"
cleanup() {
    rm -rf "${mtools_tmp}"
}
trap cleanup EXIT

rm -f "${IMG_NAME}.img"
truncate -s "$((CYLINDERS * HEADS * SECTORS * 512))" "$IMG_NAME"

mpartition -I -t "$CYLINDERS" -h "$HEADS" -s "$SECTORS" c: 2>&1
mpartition -c -T 6 -t "$CYLINDERS" -h "$HEADS" -s "$SECTORS" c:
mformat c:
mcopy -s "$SRC_DIR"/* c:
```