# Loopdevice partitions do not show up

Tags: partition, loop-device

I have a program which creates partitions and filesystems on a disk. To test it, I have created an image file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1M count=100
```

and mounted:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
```

The partitioning process seemingly works, I get an error from `mkfs`:

```
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/loop0p2: No such file or directory
```

I can see the partitions with `fdisk -l`:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0
Disk /dev/loop0: 1000 MiB, 1048576000 bytes, 2048000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B2CB131D-0091-4102-89E1-1D94EC49484A

Device         Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop0p1    2048   10239    8192    4M BIOS boot
/dev/loop0p2   10240  272383  262144  128M EFI System
/dev/loop0p3  272384 1320959 1048576  512M Linux swap
/dev/loop0p4 1320960 2047966  727007  355M Linux filesystem
```

but not with `lsblk`:

```
sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  1000M  0 loop 
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 457,3G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with `losetup --partscan`? kernel / distro version?

Comment: I have noticed that losetup --partscan fails when I specify a 4k block size to losetup.  I have to run "partscan" by itself after for the partitions to show up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `partprobe`(which is part of `parted` package) or `kpartx` so kernel will get info about partitions.

Mounting / partitioning loopback devices not always causes kernel to re-read partition table.

It is common situation when you've got info:

```
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy.
The kernel still uses old table [...]
```

You can also force kernel to re-read partition table of loopback device by using: `losetup -P` command

As stated in manual:

```
   -P, --partscan
          Force the kernel to scan the partition table on a newly created loop device.
```

Comment: "losetup -P" no longer works on an already-connected loopback device.  The -P option must be supplied at the time the loopback device is connected.